# converting array of objects into different objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects:

```
[{ bags:10, pouch:small, weight:100, quantity:1 },
 { bags:101, pouch:large, weight:1001, quantity:11 }]
```

How can I separate this array into multiple objects shown below?

```
small = { bags:10,weight:100,quantity:1 } 
large = { bags:101,weight:1001,quantity:11 }
```

Comment: I think [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is the way to go here.

Comment: @A1rPun: No, not if producing multiple outputs.

Comment: Where are you stuck? You simply find the entry for "small", create an object, copy relevant props into it, and do the same for "large."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I dont know how do copy those in order to create seperate object for each

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I must have read the question wrong :)

Comment: I suggest working through some JavaScript tutorials. Creating objects and assigning properties to them is extremely basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the steps are:

1. Find the entry you want, and
2. Create an object for the pouch
3. Copy the properties you want

So:

```js
var array = [{ bags:10,pouch:"small",weight:100,quantity:1},{bags:101,pouch:"large",weight:1001,quantity:11}];
var small = get(array, "small");
var large = get(array, "large");
snippet.log("small = " + JSON.stringify(small));
snippet.log("large = " + JSON.stringify(large));

function get(array, pouch) {
  // Find the entry (on newer browsers you could use Array#find, and it
  // can be shimmed; I used Array#some here)
  var found;
  array.some(function(entry) {
    if (entry.pouch == pouch) {
      found = entry;
      return true;
    }
  });
  if (found) {
    // Found it, create an object with the properties we want
    return {
      bags: found.bags,
      weight: found.weight,
      quantity: found.quantity
    };
  }
  return null;
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! @T.J.Crowder If the content inside the object is unknown how can I iterate  through all the values inside the object and then seperate it?

Comment: @HarshMakadia: See Nina's answer about creating an object with properties for each pouch.

Answer (score 3):

It does it, but i do not recommend it!

```js
var data = [{ bags: 10, pouch: 'small', weight: 100, quantity: 1 }, { bags: 101, pouch: 'large', weight: 1001, quantity: 11 }],
    object = data.forEach(function (a) {
        window[a.pouch] = { bags: a.bags, weight: a.weight, quantity: a.quantity };
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(small, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(large, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Better solution with an object

You can first build an object with the `pouch` values as property and assign them later to the wanted variables.

```js
var data = [{ bags: 10, pouch: 'small', weight: 100, quantity: 1 }, { bags: 101, pouch: 'large', weight: 1001, quantity: 11 }],
    object = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.pouch] = { bags: a.bags, weight: a.weight, quantity: a.quantity };
        return r;
    }, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');

var small = object.small,
    large = object.large;

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(small, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(large, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: @NinaScholz what if content inside the object is dynamically generated how do I fetch them?

Comment: @HarshMakadia, i suggest to use an object, and keep all values together.

Comment: @HarshMakadia: In that situation, as Nina says, an object (or on modern engines a `Map` if appropriate) to organize them is the right way to go about it.